# Window 8 Accelerated Open GL

Tags: windows-8, drivers, graphics-card, opengl, nvidia-ion

I updated to Windows 8, but I can't find the drivers for my graphics card, as some programs are saying that I don't have accelerated OpenGL and the fix for this is updating my graphics card.

Graphics Card: NVIDIA ION (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM v1.2) (ASUStek Computer Inc)
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 8 Pro 64-bit
Computer: ASUSTeK Computer INC. 1215N

Much appreciated if you left a link in your answer to the download page for the driver.

Thanks.

Comment: Where have you searched so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the latest driver directly from nVIDIA:

http://www.nvidia.com/object/notebook-win8-win7-winvista-64bit-310.90-whql-driver.html

Comment: Hey Magicandre1981, I downloaded the package installer, but when I ran the installer, it did a system check for compatible hardware and eventually came up with this error: 
              NVIDIA Installer cannot continue - This graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware.

Comment: use the device manager to install the driver: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9695-driver-install-device-manager-windows-8-a.html

Comment: It claims that the driver is up to date, but still no accelerated OpenGL. Maybe this might help?
I have a Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator 3150 (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.0) I also have OpenGL 1.0 which isn't the latest version.

Comment: this is an Intel GPU. Does your device support Nvidia Optimus? Also install the latest Intel drivers.

Comment: I have tried installing the latest drivers from Intel, but it comes up with the same error, where it doesn't detect the hardware. Is there a link to the correct Intel Driver? Also, I believe that my device does support Nvidia Optimus.

Comment: look with GPU-Z which GPUs you have. Now use the search in the Intel download center to get the driver.

Comment: Aah, found the problem. I don't know how to fix it though. The reason some applications weren't working was not because of the drivers, but I found this: In a program called GLview, I found something which said this: WGL_ACCELERATION_ARB: NO_ACCELERATION

Comment: this is a driver issue. It signals the program, that it doesn't support hardware acceleration.